# Hydration Error in Next13 with pocketbase auth

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js13, hydration, pocketbase

I am trying to create a navbar using pocketbase auth, I experience a hydration error when trying to use conditional rendering with `pb.authStore.isValid` My guess is that this session is only stored locally and not on the server, which makes it not render properly on the server. How do I fix this issue so I can conditionally render something if a user is logged in?

I tried to use pb.authStore.isValid to conditionally render an avatar on my page, I expected it to show up the avatar when logged in, which it did, the issue is now that it also shows up after I do `pb.authStore.clear()` and gives an hydration error:
[Hydration errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utb5S.png).

```
"use client";

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <nav className="fullwidth pt-2 flex content-center text-text pb-4">
        <div className="flex gap-4 ml-4 mr-5">
          {pb.authStore.isValid ? (
            <Link href="/profile">
             {pb.authStore.model?.avatar 
              ? 
              // eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-img-element
              <img src={pb.authStore.model?.avatar} alt={pb.authStore.model?.username + " profile"} /> 
              :   
              <div className="bg-primary text-black w-[35px] flex aspect-square justify-center transition-ease-in duration-100 items-center rounded-full border-4 hover:border-5  border-gray-800">
                {pb.authStore.model?.username[0].toUpperCase()}
              </div>
              }
            </Link>
          ) : (   
            <>
              <Link className="navbutton" href="/register">
                <Button
                  title="Sign Up"
                  onClick={() => {}}
                  variant="secondary"
                />
              </Link>
              <Link className="navbutton" href="/login">
                <Button title="Log In" onClick={() => {}} variant="primary" />
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```